# Where do we get native library .so files for javacv from?

Tags: c++, opencv, javacv, javacpp

So I'm having a problem with running some javaCV code, and though I've seen numerous fixes online for it, none have worked.

The exact error is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/javacpp/libjniopencv_core.so  cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

I looked in /usr/local/lib (where it should be looking) and I have a bunch of shared objects in that directory such as libopencv_core.so.2.4.  None of them have jni in the name though.  This makes me think I missed a step.  Where are the opencv jni so files supposed to have come from?

I'm running on a Raspberry Pi (ARM) if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer here since I answered by email last night and that approach solved the problem today in the lab.  (I mentor the robotics team trying to get javacv working.)

We gave up on struggling with it and used [Jeremy's downloadable files](http://jeremy-nicola.info/download/).  This worked better as the versions were consistent with each other.  We still don't have a jni .so file, but the older versions of javacv don't appear to use it.

I also noticed that the [Android instructions](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android2.2) give a step to compile jni but the Linux ones do not.  If we were to go back to recompiling ourselves, this would be the next thing to try.  Since compiling takes four hours, using Jeremy's pre-compiled for Raspberry Pi files are a much better option though.